# Translate CLI ImageMagick to Magick++: threshold and depth

Tags: c++, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, magick++

I am converting a `system` call to `Magick++` in my code, but I am having some trouble converting the `threshold` and `depth`.

The original:

```
convert /foo/bar.ppm -crop WxH+X+Y -threshold 50% -depth 1 /foo/out.ppm
```

My current `C++` version is:

```
Magick::InitializeMagick(*argv);
Magick::Image img;
img.read("/foo/bar.ppm");
Magick::Image temp_img(img);
temp_img.chop(Magick::Geometry(X,Y);
temp_img.crop(Magick::Geometry(W,H));
temp_img.threshold(.50);
temp_img.depth(1);
temp_img.write("/foo/out.ppm");
```

The `chop` and `crop` behaves like I expect, but the rest does not.  The `threshold` and `depth` commands take a `double` and a `size_t`, respectively.  So what I have written in there seems like it would work.  However, if either one of these lines are enabled, the result image comes out nearly all white.

Is there a more correct way of doing this?

Comment: When you use `threshold()` I think you need to pass a QuantumRange so if your version is Q16, you need to pass `65535/2`.

Comment: Thanks for the version hint.  ``QuantumRange`` wasn't working for my instance, but the manual quantum range works.  For learning purposes, why do I use half of the 16-bit range rather than an 8-bit range like the source implies [here](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/995518b96e85e322f29c36a3664114c45b0b15d2/MagickCore/magick-type.h#L70)?

Comment: The QuantumDepth, and corresponding QuantumRange, are set at compile time when **ImageMagick** is built, so they are independent of the bit-depth of the image. If you run `magick identify` you will see either `Q8` or `Q16` so you will know how it was built.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Q16 wasn't a version ID, like ``6.9.10-23``.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark Setchell's comment is correct. `Maigck::Image.threshold`'s argument must be scaled by the QuantumRange (provided by a C macro definition).

```cpp
temp_img.threshold(QuantumRange * 0.5);
```

This scaling is expected for most arguments that are a percent ratio.

Comment: After I searched SO for Magick++ answers, I was wondering if you would put an answer here!  Note that @Mark Setchell's comment was necessary to get this to work.  I tried ``QuantumRange`` before asking the question, but I guess ``apt`` provides an older version which does not include that constant.

Comment: After inspecting the result more closely, this answer does not entirely solve the problem.  The ``depth`` of the resulting file is 255 from C++ rather than 1 like when I use the bash command.

Comment: Don't know what to say. Tested both ImageMagick-6 & ImageMagick-7 output, and `Magick::Image.depth(1)` & `-depth 1` produce the same results. Perhaps you need to set the image type to bilevel, or quantize?

Comment: I've confirmed the problem on two machines.  I'm going to open a new question so we don't muddy up this perfectly fine answer.

Comment: Good idea. Might be worth including source file, or how to generate a test input image. I wouldn't be surprised if we're seeing the same thing, but are disagreeing on the expected behavoir.

Comment: I added as much detail as I could think of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141968/magick-depth-does-not-behave-the-same-as-convert-depth